# Flatlist scrollToIndex with Hooks useRef

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Im trying to scroll to the middle of my data in flatlist using React Hooks and the method scrollToIndex but i cant make reference to it. I achieved that with class using something like   ref={component => (this.list = component)} but i can reached with useRef.

```
const refContainer = useRef(null); 

useEffect(()=>{   
        if(refContainer){
            refContainer.scrollToIndex({ animated: true, index: 0 });

        }    
    },[status])

<FlatList
                ref={()=>refContainer}
                refreshing={loading}
                onRefresh={() => console.log('refreshing')}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.date}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                style={{flex: 1,}}
                data={kits}    
                onEndThreshold={0}
                renderItem={({item, index}) => renderItem(item, index)}   

            />
```

shows me the error: refContainer.scrollToINdex is not a function.

Comment: What's the `status` variable here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To access the ref of the current render, you need to use `.current` - so in your case, use `refContainer.current`:

```
useEffect(()=>{   
        if(refContainer.current){
            refContainer.current.scrollToIndex({ animated: true, index: 0 });

        }    
    },[status])
```

Also, set up your ref like this:

```
<FlatList ref={refContainer} ...
```

(See the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) for more info on `.current`)

Comment: please  provide a complete solutions because refContainer.current is always null and where does status come from?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Create ref for flatlist , for example see below ,

```
     let myList = useRef();
```

Step 2 :  Then  add  ref  to  your  flatlist  component  like this

```
    <FlatList
    data = {data}
    ref={myList}
    renderItem = {YourComponent}
    initialScrollIndex={0}
    horizontal = {true}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
   />
```

Step 3  Then scroll the flatlist on any button click or any event like below

```
   myList.current.scrollToIndex({animated:true,index:0,viewPosition:0});
```

Thanks! Hope it helps

Comment: this doesnt help myList is null