# How to move image down to make space for the search result dynamically(React native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

There is image below my search input box, and I want it to move down when a user type anything, below search input box a search result box appears, and below that there should be image and when search field is cleared there is no search result box so the image should move again upwards. How can i achieve this scenario?

Comment: could you create a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/)?

Comment: Just wanted to know the procedure.. I will upload the current code in a while

Comment: You should use a Flatlist, access the scroll method using refs. Scroll when the data arrives.

Comment: so flatlist should be declared in curly braces right like { this.props.data!=' '  && <Flatlist ..../>} and inside check if the data arrived or not then print right?

Comment: yeah and you could ref to access the flatlist and scroll on useEffect

Comment: can you give eg using ref?

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60566164/flatlist-scrolltoindex-with-hooks-useref)

Comment: ok I will try and will let you know, where can i ping you?

Comment: just here........

Answer (score 0):

you can set **state** like as flag for show or hidden your search result

for example

```
{(this.state.showResult == true)?
<view>
your search result view 
</view>
:null
}
```